# Correlating volumes and physical disks through WMI

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wmi

I'm trying to correlate volumes (as enumerated from `win32_volume` for those where `DriveType = 3`) back to `win32_physicaldisk` instances. Everything that I've seen in my research points to the answer being "it's not possible", but then again, I didn't read the entire Internet. :) I'm currently getting the information out of diskpart, but am running into limitations with that approach.

As a bonus, if the answer is "no, and here's the reason why", that would be useful, too.

Comment: If you're fortunate enough to be using Server 2012+ everywhere, you can use the Get-Partition and Get-Disk cmdlets for PowerShell 4.  If not, well, yeah, back to your question... which I'd like top know the answer to as well.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: I am that fortunate. At a quick glance, this might work. However, it doesn't seem to be listing volumes that don't currently have an access path (i.e. drive letter or mount point). That would be a show stopper for this particular application.

Comment: not sure if i'm completely off base, but what about using a different class, like Win32_LogicalDisk? It looks like it supports the same DriveType method, and links to physicaldisk better.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't necessarily answer the wmi question but here's an alternative.  Use a diskpart script and parse out the results.

Create a diskpart script like so:

```
select disk 3
list volume
```

Execute the diskpart script from powershell (or something to parse out the results):

```
$volumes = diskpart /s myDiskpartScript.txt
$volumes |? {$_ -match 'Volume (\d)'} |% {$matches[1]}
```

This will grab all the volumes associated with disk 3 and output the capture group from the regex match to show each volume number.  You can add additional capture groups to grab information like the label, file system type, and more.

Unfortunately this isn't a remote method and may not suit your needs, but still may be useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

You sohuld use:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskPartition
```

and

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskPartition | Select-Object -Property *
```

Can also be used to query remote computers for this information.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specifically volumes->disks, but you could pipe the partitions in to Get-Disk. For example, this will tell you the disk associated with drive letter C:

```
Get-Partition -DriveLetter C | Get-Disk
```

(Tested on PS version 5.1)